# Is there a higher chance of the Sham Shield dropping elsewhere?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've beem farming the B3NKR for the Sham Shield for several hours now; I know percentages are low for legendary drops, yet I thought I'd check. Is there any better place to attempt to acquire this? Or anyone that would be willing to dupe one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a legendary item, The Sham can technically be dropped anywhere (even bought as a special deal at the Medical Vending Machine : see image below). However the drop rate is higher **only** at the BNK-3R (5% if I'm not mistaken). Take care once you killed the BNK-3R, when the items drop they can often glitch and fall "trough" the ground, you then only see the beam above the item which can lead to you missing The Sham even though it dropped, so pay full attention while looting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, boss. I've had that happen once or twice, at The Warrior's place too. I'll be sure to pay better attention though. I was hoping there was a better place for it, but thanks for the advice!! +1

Comment: Oh absolutely. I play on PS3, my gamertag matches my username

Comment: @Evil_Yoshiii okay, too bad you don'tp play on steam, i could've helped you. Anyway good luck, when I first farmed it it took me about 90min

Comment: pity. I'd enjoy it, but hey I'll get there! Thanks. I might try farming a vending machine to have a break from B3NKR. It only takes me about twenty seconds to kill him in TVHM must still. haha

Comment: But still* ha oops